# Show F(x) = $\sup_{\substack{0 \leq t \leq1}}$ x(t) is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Show F(x) = $\sup_{\substack{0 \leq t \leq1}}$ x(t) is continuous

x(t) is defined on the interval [0, 1] and the functional F(x) is defined on the space C of all continuous functions on the interval [0, 1]

The problem comes from an example in section 12 in Kolmogorov's Introductory Real Analysis.

The given solution to the problem states that the functional F is continuous on C since $\rho$(x, y) = sup |x - y| and |sup x - sup y| $\leq$ sup |x - y|.

This reasoning is completely lost on me. It would be incredibly helpful if someone could go through the logic and fill in the gaps as to why this actually proves the statement.

Comment: Since $x$ is continuous, the supremum is attained, say at $t_x\in [0,1]$, i.e. $x(t_x) = F(x) = \sup \{ x(t) : t\in [0,1]\}$. Now take $x,y$, and suppose without loss of generality that $F(x) \geqslant F(y)$. Then $F(x) - F(y) = x(t_x) - y(t_y) \leqslant x(t_x) - y(t_x) \leqslant \sup \{ x(t) - y(t) : t\in [0,1]\} \leqslant \rho(x,y)$.

Comment: I'm trying to think of this as an epsilon delta proof. So, for $\epsilon$ > 0 then $\rho(x, y) = sup \{x(t) - y(t):t\in[0,1]\} < \delta < \epsilon$ implies that $F(x) - F(y) = x(t_x) - y(t_y) \leq x(t_x) - y(t_x) \leq \rho(x, y) < \epsilon$

Thus for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - y| < \delta \Rightarrow |F(x) - F(y)| < \epsilon$ holds whenever $\delta < \epsilon$ ?

Comment: You forgot a modulus in $\rho$. If we get rid of the assumption $F(x) \geqslant F(y)$ - by interchanging the roles if $F(y) > F(x)$ - then we obtain $\lvert F(x) - F(y)\rvert \leqslant \rho(x,y)$. So $\delta = \varepsilon$ works.

Comment: Okay, but other than that my epsilon delta reasoning looks good?

Comment: Pretty much. You need to at least mention symmetry, or  make the assumption $F(x) \geqslant (y)$, or so to get from $F(x) - F(y) < \epsilon$ to $\lvert F(x) - F(y)\rvert < \epsilon$, but the gist is okay.

Comment: You've cleared up all the questions I have. If you want to type it up as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x$ is continuous, the supremum is attained, i.e. for every $x\in C([0,1])$, there is a $t_x\in [0,1]$ with

$$F(x) = \sup \{ x(t) : t \in [0,1]\} = x(t_x).$$

Thus, for any $x,y\in C([0,1])$ we have

$$F(x) - F(y) = x(t_x) - y(t_y) \leqslant x(t_x) - y(t_x) \leqslant \sup \{x(t) - y(t) : t\in [0,1]\} \leqslant \rho(x,y).$$

By symmetry,

$$F(y) - F(x) = y(t_y) - x(t_x) \leqslant y(t_y) - x(t_y) \leqslant \rho(x,y),$$

and hence

$$\lvert F(x) - F(y)\rvert \leqslant \rho(x,y).$$

Thus $F$ is Lipschitz-continuous with Lipschitz constant $1$.